# How to get the expanded row value in react-table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-table, react-table-v7

I have created a react-table in Material UI. Here I got a task like expanding the row. I did that expansion functionality But I don't know how to get the expanded value over there.

Here is the working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-with-material-ui-expandable-ygvc6c?file=/table/materialTable.js).

Please tell me how to get the expanded row value in that. Like that entire row object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The row object should be under `row.original`. You can try something like this to test it:

```
{
  row.isExpanded ? (
    <tr>
      <td>
        {`hello ${JSON.stringify(row.original, null, 2)}}`}
        {console.log("originalObj === ", row.original)}
      </td>
    </tr>
  ) : null;
}
```

The above code won't look pretty when rendered, but it should help you achieve your goal :)

Comment: Thanks it works, But is there any way we can get that as a array of object instead of an array

Comment: You mean you want the initial array containing all the data used for the table instead of the object containing the row data? Or you want each cell data? Or what exactly do you mean by `array of object instead of an array` ? :)